# augmenting a nested json array in a dict and then passing output array objects to elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, fluentd

I have some polled data sources which i want to pass to Elasticsearch:

```
{ "foo": { "bar": [
  {"name": "Hello", "route":"5A", "lat":"2345678", "lon":"2345678" },
  {"name": "World", "route":"5D", "lat":"8765432", "lon":"8798765" },
]}}
```

Ideally I want to pass all the array contents to Elasticsearch to be created as documents.

want to take the passed in JSON, unwrap it, and then essentially run a filter to add a new kv pair:

```
<filter>
  @type record_transformer
  <record>
    geo_coord "{lat},{lon}"
  </record>
</filter>
```

Which seems pretty simple to me.

Ideally I want to have fluentd handle the polling of 6 websites, then ingest as above, and submit them as documents to elastic i set up.

I am currently just working through a docker container to see if i can get this all working, so right now I am trying to do some simple tests with std out.

Ultimately, i catch the above payload but how do i add a new property to each of the list items? After I get done the parsing of data, then i should easily be able to ship it to Elasticsearch.

Comment: Are you facing any issues? IMO, dumping to STDOUT is ideal for testing. Besides, and please correct me if I'm wrong, I don't see any questions in your post.

Comment: Ill adjust to emphasise the questions at the bottom

Comment: You can use [enable_ruby](https://docs.fluentd.org/filter/record_transformer#enable_ruby) and write code to process the list according to your requirements.